# CSS - HTML how to make the anchor image go to a specific spot

Tags: html, css

I want all of the anchor images in different corners , eg , top left , top right , bottom right , bottom right , and one in the centre thank you

How do I make all my anchor links / images go to specific sides I want the teams one on top left I want store top right sponsors bottom left and about us bottom right I thought I did all the right code but they don't how up in those specific spots

If anyone can help it will be greatly appreciates

**Code**

http://pastebin.com/Yjth4U93

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/LL4orf6p/)**

**Css**

```
.section-links { position: relative; height: 500px; background-color: #c3c3c3 ; }
.section-links a { position: absolute; }
.section-links a.top-left { top: 10px; left: 10px; }
.section-links a.top-right { top: 10px; right: 10px; }
.section-links a.bottom-left { bottom: 10px; left: 10px; }
.section-links a.bottom-right { bottom: 10px; right: 10px; }
```

**Html**

```
<div class="section-links">
  <a href="teams.html" class="top-left">
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="icon1.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="teams.html" class="top-right">
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="icon2.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="teams.html" class="bottom-left">
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="icon4.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="teams.html" class="bottom-right">
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="icon3.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your code the images are going on all corners etc. I'm not sure what you asking. You want bellow the images to have some links?

Comment: when i open it in chrome all my images stay aliened and they are not in all corners

Comment: I moved your code to `jsfiddle` to better testing, ok please see this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/LL4orf6p/) and tell us what is your problem exactly? I see all your image in corners.

Comment: do you want multiple link on single image or what?

Comment: I know the images are small I'm going to fix that when the images go in the right corners , here's my problem http://imgur.com/2gJjdW4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
```

css

```
.section-links {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3 ;
}

.top-left {
  top: 10px; left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px; right: 10px;
}
.bottom-left {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 10px; left: 10px;
}
.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px; right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I feel so dumb lol i did have that code but my friend said it wasn't right